# Вывод даты определеннного коммита в Console - C#

Tags: c#, git, git-commit, repository

*Добрый день!*

Можно ли вывести дату определенного коммита (имееться только название его) удаленно, с помощью метода **Repository.ListRemoteReferences(link)**?
Использую библиотеку **LibGit2Sharp**.

Comment: нет. нельзя. Потому что у коммита нет имени. Но есть как минимум три  вещи, которые могут претендовать на "название коммита" - имя ветки, имя тега и "сообщение коммита". И если с первыми двумя ещё как то можно попробовать  решить задачу, то с третьим - достаточно сложно - сообщение коммита не объязано быть уникальным.

Comment: @KoVadim эм, а айдишник (хэш) коммита?

Comment: ну я же написал "минимум три". Но все таки hash - это hash, а не имя.

Comment: имееться hash коммита. Извиняюсь за ошибку

Comment: [tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru)

Comment: @VladislavsGeidans в этом случае нужно получить commit object. Там будет достаточно информации. Как сделать этой либой - а кто его знает.

Comment: Тонко! Я не русский. Поэтому тонкостей языка не знаю!

Comment: Ну вот поэтому я не знаю как мне всё это сделать... А очень даже хочеться!

Comment: самый простой способ сделать то, что Вы хотите - склонировать репу себе. А там будет простор.

Comment: Скорее всего нельзя. В чем проблема склонировать?

Comment: и `Repository.ListRemoteReferences` возвращает `Reference` а не `Commit`

Comment: Использование клонирование, не разумно, ибо вывод информации о последнем коммите будет выводиться с очень большого количества репозиториев.

Comment: Простым языком, вывод информации будет реализован через цикл, в котором будут перечесляться ссылки репозиториев

Comment: Попробуйте открыть Issue на github, должны написать есть такая возможность или нет.

Comment: В крайнем случае полезете в исходники и добавите такой функционал.

Comment: Ну я думаю, что там ничего подобного.

Comment: Да и я думаю, что всё должно быть на много всё проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, нет способа получить информацию о коммитах удалённого репозитория 
без его клонирования используя библиотеку LibGit2Sharp.

Метод `IEnumerable<Reference> ListRemoteReferences(string url)` 
аналогичен git-команде [git-ls-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote/2.8.0) и способен получить информацию только о ветках и тегах вместе с хешами коммитов.